# App thinning for custom assets

Tags: ios

I'm writing a game and i'd love to have multiple asset packages (these are .dat files) for different iOS devices (768p iPad, 1536p iPad, 640p iPhone, 750p iPhones, 1080p iPhones).

Is achievable via App Thinning feature ?

I know unity allows this somehow
https://blogs.unity3d.com/cn/2015/12/28/optimizing-ios-app-size-with-resource-slicing/

I'm using Xamarin, but if its achievable via some command line tools of XCode - thats okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: No, resolution-based segmentation is impossible.

Seems that Apple doesn't allow direct by-resolution segmentation for generic data assets.

You can segment by **memory**, **metal support** and **device type**.

Textures extend this list with **scale** (1x, 2x, 3x)